# Call to Kubernetes service failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

kubernetes version: 1.5.2
os: centos 7
etcd version: 3.4.0

First, I create an etcd pod, the etcd dockerfile and etcd pod YAML file like this:
etcd dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

COPY . /usr/bin
WORKDIR /usr/bin

CMD etcd --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379

EXPOSE 2379
```

pod yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: etcd
  namespace: storageplatform
  labels:
    app: etcd
spec:
  containers:
    - name: etcd
      image: "karldoenitz/etcd:3.4.0"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 2379
          hostPort: 12379
```

After created the docker image and push to dockerhub, I run the command `kubectl apply -f etcd.yaml` to create the etcd pod.
The ip of etcd pod is `10.254.140.117`, I ran the command use `ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=175.24.47.64:12379 put 1 1` and got `OK`.
My service yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: storageservice
  namespace: storageplatform
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 12379
      targetPort: 12379
      nodePort: 32379
  selector:
    app: etcd
```

apply the yaml file to create the service.run the command `kubectl get services -n storageplatform`, I got these infomation.

```
NAMESPACE         NAME                   CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
storageplatform   storageservice         10.254.140.117   <nodes>       12379:32379/TCP   51s
```

After all, I run the command

```sh
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=10.254.140.117:32379 get 1
```

or

```sh
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints={host-ip}:32379 get 1
```

I got `Error: context deadline exceeded`.

What's the matter? How to make the service useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the service to refer to `containerPort` instead of `hostPort`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: storageservice
  namespace: storageplatform
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 2379
      targetPort: 2379
      nodePort: 32379
  selector:
    app: etcd
```

Answer (score 4):

You defined a service that is available inside the kubernetes network using the service name/ip (10.254.140.117 ) and the service port (12379) and which is available on ALL nodes of the kubernetes cluster even outside the kubernetes network with the node port (32379)

You need to fix the service in order to map to the correct container port: `targetPort` must match the pod `containerPort` (and the port in the dockerfile).

If the error `Error: context deadline exceeded` persits, it hints at a communication problem. This can be explained when using the internal service ip with the external node port (your first get 1). For the node port (your second command) I assume that either the etcd pod is not running properly, or the port is firewalled on the node.